# Scrape multiple pages in scrapy but data is overwritten

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Data are overwritten and they give the data of only last page how to solve these problem is any solution for these kindly recommend me I've seen several solutions to scrape multiple pages from a website, but couldn't make it work on my code.these is the page link https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.http import Request


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    url = 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php'
    
    k=1
    u=10
    for n in range(5):
        k += 10
        u+= 10 
        payload='tuusan_year=&tuusan_month=&tuusan_chk=&methodAndOr1=&methodAndOr2=&methodAndOr3=&text_sen=&text_skill=&text_business=&tokkyo_data=&fuki_day_chk=&shuju=&kensyuu_bunya=&text_kensyuu=&methodAndOr_kensyuu=&keitai_kikan=&keitai_hisu=&display_flag=1&search=2&text=&method=&methodAndOr=&area=&pref=&name=&kana=&id=&year=&month=&day=&day_chk=&exp01=&exp02=&exp03=&trip=&venture_support=&venture_flag=&university_support=&university_flag=&university1=&university2=&university=&college=&high_pref=&junior_pref=&elementary_pref=&tyosaku=&hp=&jukoureki=&experience1=&experience2=&experience3=&experience4=&sort=&fuki_year=&fuki_month=&fuki_day=&fuki_day_chk=&id_chk=&shugyou=&fuki=&address1=&address2=&trip_pref=&expref=&office=&max_count=1438&search_count=10&start_count='+str(k)+'&search_default='+str(u)
        
       
        
        headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cookie': 'CAKEPHP=u6u40lefkqnm45j49a5i0h6bs3; __utma=42336182.871903078.1657200864.1657200864.1657200864.1; __utmz=42336182.1657200864.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
        'Origin': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com',
        'Referer': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
        }
        
        def start_requests(self):
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                url=self.url,
                method='POST',
                body=self.payload,
                headers=self.headers,
                callback=self.parse_item,
                    )
            
            
        def parse_item(self, response):
            base_url="https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/"
            links =response.xpath("//table[4]//tr")
            for link in links[1:]:
                t=link.xpath("//form//@action").get()
                u=link.xpath(".//input[@name='serial']//@value").get()
                product=base_url+t+"?serial="+u+"&office_serial=&submit2=Details"
                yield Request(product,callback=self.parse_book)
                        
        def parse_book(self,response):
            name=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Name')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
                    
            telephone=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'TEL')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
            
            fax=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'FAX')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
            
            email=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Email')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
            
            website=response.xpath("//td[text()[contains(.,'Website')]]/following-sibling::td//a[starts-with(@href, 'http')]/@href").get()
            
            
            registration_date=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Registration date')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
            
            
            firm=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Firm Name')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
            
            
            address=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Address (Prefecture)')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get()
            
            
            
            spec=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Specialization')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get().replace(" ï½œ","|")
            
            
            tech=response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[text()[contains(.,'Technical field')]]/following-sibling::td//text())").get().replace(" ï½œ","|")
            
            
            yield{
            "name":name,
            "Telephone":telephone,
            "Fax":fax,
            "Email":email,
            "website":website,
            "Registration_date":registration_date,
            "Firm_name":firm,
            "Address":address,
            "Specialization":spec,
            "Technical_field":tech
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all results in a single post request do the following:

```
import requests

cookies = {}
headers = {}
data = {
    'submit2': 'Display',
    'search_default': '1500',
    'sort': '',
    'tuusan_year': '',
    'tuusan_month': '',
    'tuusan_chk': '',
    'methodAndOr1': '',
    'methodAndOr2': '',
    'methodAndOr3': '',
    'text_sen': '',
    'text_skill': '',
    'text_business': '',
    'tokkyo_data': '',
    'fuki_day_chk': '',
    'shuju': '',
    'kensyuu_bunya': '',
    'text_kensyuu': '',
    'methodAndOr_kensyuu': '',
    'keitai_kikan': '',
    'keitai_hisu': '',
    'search': '2',
    'area': '',
    'pref': '',
    'name': '',
    'kana': '',
    'id': '',
    'year': '',
    'month': '',
    'day': '',
    'address1': '',
    'address2': '',
    'trip_pref': '',
    'day_chk': '',
    'exp01': '',
    'exp02': '',
    'exp03': '',
    'trip': '',
    'venture_support': '',
    'venture_flag': '',
    'university_support': '',
    'university_flag': '',
    'university': '',
    'college': '',
    'high_pref': '',
    'junior_pref': '',
    'elementary_pref': '',
    'tyosaku': '',
    'hp': '',
    'jukoureki': '',
    'experience1': '',
    'experience2': '',
    'experience3': '',
    'experience4': '',
    'fuki_year': '',
    'fuki_month': '',
    'fuki_day': '',
    'display_flag': '1',
    'id_chk': '',
    'shugyou': '',
    'fuki': '',
    'expref': '',
    'office': '',
    'start_count': '1',
    'end_count': '10',
    'max_count': '1438',
    'search_count': '10',
    's': '1',
    'shozaichi': '',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
response.text
```

Just need to clean up the data output and your done.

Prints (truncated output for SO, will contain everything of interest):

```
'\ufeff<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">\n<html lang="ja">\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<title>Japan Patent Attorney Search</title>\n\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="../01.css" type="text/css">\n<script language="JavaScript" src="../js/win.js"></script>\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">\n<!--\nfunction kensakuClick(){//検索\n  document.form.action=\'./english1_2.php\';\n  document.form.submit();\n}\nfunction siborikomiClick(){//更に絞り込む\n  document.form.action=\'../english/english1.php\';\n  document.form.submit();\n}\n//-->\n</script>\n<style type="text/css">\n<!--\n.style3 {color: #FFFFFF}\n-->\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n  <tr>\n    <td width="750"><div align="center"><img src="../images/head2.gif" alt="日本弁理士会" width="750" height="12"><br>\n\n     <!--パンくずリスト-->\n     <table width="690" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">\n        <tr height="25">\n          <td width="670" height="25"><a href="/" class="fontsizeset" >Home(Japanese)</a>\u3000&gt;\n      <a href="./english1.php?search=2" class="fontsizeset" >Japan Patent Attorney Search</a>\n    \u3000</td>\n        </tr>\n        <tr>\n          <td width="670"></td>\n        </tr>\n      </table>\n\n        <!--「マルチ検索(弁理士)」タブ-->\n        <!--<table width="690" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n          <tr>\n            <td><img src="images/tab.gif" alt="マルチ検索(弁理士)" width="230" height="48" border="0"></td>\n          </tr>\n        </table>-->\n        <table width="690" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="4" bgcolor="#ffa48c">\n          <tr>\n            <td valign="top" width="642" height="487" bgcolor="#ffede3"><div align="center">\n                                        <table width="608" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">\n                  <tr height="29">\n                    <td width="596" height="29"><span class="f14"><strong>■Search results</strong></span></td>\n                  </tr>\n                </table>\n                <br>\n                <table width="608" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="#a8a8a8">\n                  <tr height="12">\n                    <td bgcolor="white" height="12"><table width="100%">\n                        <tr>\n                          <td>\n                            1438                            matches found using these search parameters</td>\n                        </tr>\n                    </table></td>\n                  </tr>\n                </table>\n                 <form method="POST" name="form">\n                  <table width="608" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">\n                    <!--1行目-->\n                    <tr height="20">\n                      <td height="20">\n                        <table width="100%">\n                          <tr>\n                            <!--「～件中～件表示」-->\n                                                         <td width="320">Displaying results 1 -1438 of 1438                            </td>\n                            <td width="60"></td>\n                            <td width="200"></td>\n                          </tr>\n                        </table>\n                      </td>\n                    </tr>\n\n                    <!--2行目-->\n                    <tr height="20">\n                      <td height="20">\n                        <table width="100%">\n
```

You might be able to tweak the post request a little to get also the hidden output.
Good luck.

Comment: they show these error `connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion connection lost`

Comment: you could try to add cookies = { 'CAKEPHP': '7qm3qb6oimkh9e21dbg6nogqk7',}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com/english/english1_2.php',
    'Origin': 'https://www.benrishi-navi.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
}

Comment: It does work on my system, but just found that the detail list is retrieved from a second post request with unique serial number, so this will still take you 1500 seperate post requests..